# Безопасность использования методов расширения

Tags: c#, методы

Как я понимаю, методы самого класса в приоритете перед методами расширения.

Возникает закономерный вопрос:

А что будет, если я вот наплодил методы расширения, а потом через какое-то время выходит новая версия библиотеки, где определен точно такой же метод в классе. Выходит, он будет в приоритете и может работать несколько иначе — все поломается.

Получается, методы расширения — это опасная штука?

Вот пример:

```
public class Person
{
    public void Say()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
    }
}

public static class Test
{
    public static void Say(this Person p)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2");
    }
}

class Program
{         
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new Person();
        t.Say();
    } 
}
```

Допустим, мы реализовали метод `Say` в виде расширения и он выводил нам `2`, затем приходит обновление либы и тут бац и выводится `1`. Никаких предупреждений компилятор не выдает, хотя он выдает предупреждение в том случае если мы наследуемся и объявляем метод с такой же сигнатурой и он просит написать `new`.

Еще забавно, что нельзя контролировать вызов конкретного метода-расширения, если есть пересечения между пространствами имен. В этом случае единственный вариант- это вызов через статику, что убивает удобство использования расширений.

Comment: Пока Вы не перекомпилируете код, будут использоваться методы расширения. После перекомпиляции, будут использованны собственные методы класса. А так, да, Ваша программа может поломаться. Но она может поломаться даже если, к примеру, библиотека удалит нигде неиспользуемый внутренний класс.

Comment: @PetSerAl, тогда в чем смысл запечатывания классов? Вроде, их вводили с целью обезопасить пользователя, что бы разработчики класса могли все что угодно творить в своем классе, а пользователям дали расширения. Получается, что расширения тоже могут ломаться...

Comment: Извините, но я не вижу при чём тут вообще запечатывание классов.

Comment: @Паджерс, расширения **НЕ МЕНЯЮТ** расширяемый класс. Это просто синтаксический сахар, чтобы удобнее писать вызов статических функций, одним из параметров которых является объект расширяемого класса.

Comment: @Grundy, да, но разве этот синтаксичский сахар не сломает код, если поставщик выпустит новую версию класса с реализованными методами, которые ранее были реализованы в моих расширениях. Вот этого я боюсь

Comment: Синтаксический сахар, сам по себе, ничего не может сломать :-) Но да, в итоге реализация может отличаться от ожидаемой.

Comment: Однако вероятность того, что автор библиотеки угадает с типом возвращаемого значения и типами и количеством параметров - крайне мала :)

Comment: @Grundy Мала, но вероятность есть, а зафорсить то, что именно мой экстеншн всегда будет браться нельзя=(

Comment: Ну и скажем выбора вообще в таком случае не остается, даже, если в расширениях я описал всю для себя необходимую логику и я хочу продолжить пользоваться ею...

Comment: как [один из вариантов](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8048787/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy , я тоже подумал про интерфейсы, так как практически неизменяемы. Но есть классы без интерфейсов=), например FileInfo, а он вообще запечатан=> разработчики могут делать с ним все, что захотят небоясь проблем с наследниками. Реализовал я допустим там расширение с логикой, которая мне нужны. Выходит новая версия фреймворка, где добавился реальный метод с таким названием и сигнатурой, но иной логикой и все ломается, а компилятор меня не предупреждает даже...

Comment: И забавно, что еще нельзя контролировать вызов конкретного расширения , если есть пересечение между пространствами имен. Получается, что все удобство расширений разбивается об скалы...

Comment: Просто нужно быть готовым к любым неприятностям. Когда вышел .NET Framework 4.5, он устанавливался не рядом с другими (как было со всеми предыдущими), а поверх .NET 4.0 (затирал его). Это тогда вызвало немало проблем... Это был конкретный косяк! Новую версию библиотеки вас никто не заставляет применять, если полностью удовлетворяет старая. А вот то что код, прекрасно работавший ранее, внезапно ломался на новой версии фреймворка (установлена у клиента), предусмотреть было невозможно.

Comment: Перед использованием новой версии библиотеки делайте полное тестирование ваших проектов, как модульное, так и нагрузочное. Проблема должна быть найдена на этой стадии. А дальше поиск и замена по всему проекту.

Comment: @Паджерс, как запечатанность может влиять на возможность разработчиков делать с ним все что угодно? :-) Если они все-таки допилят расширения - можно будет указывать что класс имплементирует интерфейс из твоей сборки - и тогда проблема решится сама собой.

Comment: У меня очень похожая проблема. Если есть решение, напишите пожалуйста ответ.

Comment: @Паджерс Изменил метки, так как методы расширения ничем не отличаются от обычных статических методов для среды выполнения .NET, это часть языка C# и VB.NET. От обычных методов их отличает лишь наличие атрибута [`Extension`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.extensionattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 9):

> Получается, методы расширения — это опасная штука?

Да, это несомненно так. Методы расширения — грубый хак, нарушающий принципы объектно-ориентированного программирования, и помимо проблемы неконтролируемого скрытия членами расширяемого класса они также страдают от проблемы конфликтов между самими собой (ведь разные библиотеки могут создавать методы расширения для одного класса). Чрезмерно использовать их не стоит.

[Framework Design Guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/extension-methods) явно не рекомендуют это:

> **AVOID** frivolously defining extension methods, especially on types you don’t own.

Там же упоминают два случая, когда использование методов расширения оправдано:

- Добавление какого-либо функционала во все типы, реализующие определенный интерфейс. В этом случае опасность несколько ниже, ведь в интерфейсы обычно не добавляют новые методы (так как это требовало бы переписывания кода кучи классов, которые уже реализуют этот интерфейс). Именно таким образом работает LINQ.
- Методы, завязанные на типы, определенные в вашем собственном коде. Допустим, вы создаете метод расширения к классу `String`, принимающий аргумент типа `Person`, определенного в вашем проекте. В этом случае описанного конфликта также не будет, ведь даже если MS добавят новый метод в класс `String`, он точно никак не будет использовать класс из вашего кода.

К сожалению, следование этим рекомендациям все равно полностью не решает проблемы, так как остаются конфликты между самими методами расширений из разных библиотек. Именно [с этой проблемой](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/issues/351) столкнулись разработчики библиотеки MoreLinq.

Конечно, Framework Design Guidelines — это рекомендации для разработчиков публичных API библиотек, а не любого кода в приложениях. Но сути это мало меняет, так как нужно стремиться делать любой код пригодным к повторному использованию. Проекты имеют тенденцию расти, разделяться и т.п; какой-то код, который раньше использовался только в одном проекте, впоследствии захочется вынести в общую библиотеку. Поэтому эти рекомендации во многом можно распространить и на код приложений.

---

**Обновление.** В C# 8.0 появилась новая возможность - [методы интерфейсов по умолчанию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/default-interface-methods-versions). Благодаря ей, библиотеки могут добавлять новые методы в интерфейс, не нарушая обратной совместимости. Поэтому, для методов расширения интерфейсов теперь также существует проблема потенциального скрытия методом расширяемого интерфейса.

С другой стороны, это нововведение уменьшает необходимость писать методы расширения для добавления функционала в интерфейсы, так как этот функционал можно теперь реализовать в виде методов по умолчанию.