# Возможные проблемы с модификатором in

Tags: c#, .net

Читал про новые фичи C# и ключевое слово `in` для параметров.

Пример структуры с методом, параметры которого помечены `in`:

```
public struct Point3D
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
    public double Z;

    public Point3D(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.Z = z;
    }

    public static double CalculateDistance(in Point3D point1, in Point3D point2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in");
        // код опущен за ненадобностью
        return 0;
    }        
}
```

Использование:

```
Point3D a = new Point3D();
Point3D b = new Point3D();

Point3D.CalculateDistance(a, b);
Point3D.CalculateDistance(in a, in b);
```

Метод можно вызвать как с указанием `in`, так и без него. В обоих случаях вызвается этот метод.

Если теперь добавить перегрузку метода без модификатора `in`:

```
public static double CalculateDistance(Point3D point1, Point3D point2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("oops");
    // код опущен за ненадобностью
    return 0;
}
```

то предыдущий код вызова станет в одном из случаев вызывать эту перегрузку:

```
Point3D.CalculateDistance(a, b);       // выведет oops
Point3D.CalculateDistance(in a, in b); // выведет in
```

То есть при добавлении метода может сломаться работа кода, который до этого работал правильно.

Как вы считаете, косяк это?

Дополнение. Мне почему это кажется не совсем правильным: методы с модификаторами параметров `ref` и `out` не позволяют их вызова без этих модификаторов. Соответственно, описанная ситуация невозможна. Казалось бы, и для `in` должно быть такое же поведение.

PS: недавно была тема [Безопасность использования методов расширения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/906663/184217), в которой обсуждалось похожая проблема: при добавлении метода в класс перестанет вызываться метод расширения с такой же сигнатурой - код сломается.

PPS: Я понимаю, что `in` следует использовать только с `readonly struct`.

Comment: Это не косяк. По сути, если ты создаёшь только один метод с модификатором in, то он создаёт сразу же и перегрузку без этого модификатора. То есть ты можешь использовать его, как с in, так и без. Разница, как ты понимаешь небольшая: в одном случае struct не копируется и передаётся по ссылке, в другом создаётся копия. Объединяет их одно - оба случая гарантируют, что переменная не изменится. То, что ты можешь перегрузить, лишь даёт тебе возможность поменять реализацию, но это не значит, что эту реализацию нужно ломать. Более того, в коде при вызове метода, ты так же можешь явно указывать in.

Comment: @John Может имеет смысл написать это как ответ? Даже в таком виде вполне себе информативно.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov - комментарий Джона я отметил полезным (прочёл), однако такой ответ минусну. Причины распишу в комментариях ниже.

Comment: @John - _создаёт сразу же и перегрузку без этого модификатора_ - зачем создаёт? _можешь использовать его, как с in, так и без_ - вот это-то и странно.

Comment: _Разница, как ты понимаешь небольшая_ - нет, разница огромная. Мало того, что код может сломаться, так ещё и производительность может отличаться кардинально.

Comment: _но это не значит, что эту реализацию нужно ломать_ - я не хочу ломать, я хочу иметь гарантию, что код не сломается случайно.

Comment: _в коде при вызове метода, ты так же можешь явно указывать in_ - а могу не указывать: в этом вся проблема. Методы с модификаторами параметров `ref` и `out` не позволяют их вызова без этих модификаторов. Почему так же не сделали для `in`?

Comment: Не сломается. Отталкивайся от сути: для чего нужен модификатор `in`? Чтобы передать по ссылке, но при этом гарантировать неизменность. То есть гарантии те же, что и обычном вызове метода без модификатора. Да, производительность разная и ты **это** выбираешь, но отработает программа абсолютно также! И кстати, ты метод с модификатором `ref` и `out` так же можешь перегрузить и сломать всё, но ты почему-ту не задаёшься таким вопросом.

Comment: @John - метод с модификаторами `ref/out` **невозможно** вызвать без них.

Comment: Вообще, правильный (на мой взгляд) ответ кроется в последнем предложении моего поста: _in следует использовать только с readonly struct_ - при следовании этому правилу проблема уходит.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov по поводу того, что невозможно вызвать - вы правы. Действительно, если до этого был только метод с in, которое одно возвращал, то можно сломать всё и вернуть в перегрузке другое. А вообще in можно и с не readonly структурами использовать. Попробуйте создать структуру, которая имеет открытое поле и изменить его внутри метода с in - ругнётся. Или не дай бог создать метод у такой структуры, которое это поле меняет (это изначально хреновый подход) и вызвать внутри метода с in - не ругнётся, но и не изменит.

Comment: Я так вижу только одну причину такого подхода. Безболезненный переход на метод с in. Если у вас есть библиотека, которой пользуются множество людей, то вы при желании можете добавить модификатор и это вообще ничего не изменит у других. Просто появится возможность добавлять in и тем самым ускорять приложение. А так внутри вашего приложения - вы хозяин, а для других вы и так можете сломать у них что хотите поменяв реализацию уже существующего кода.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Может, конкурс объявите? Интересный у вас вопрос.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Кстати, на enSO пробовали то же самое спросить? Там аудитория побольше будет.

Comment: [in method overload resolution tiebreaker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-3#in-method-overload-resolution-tiebreaker) - тьфу ты, они "пофиксили" баг не в ту сторону.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, это не косяк. Дело в том, что Microsoft руководствуются принципом: «Не трогай, если работает». И у них появилась вот такая ситуация (вместо `int` может быть какая-нибудь `Matrix` из `System.Windows.Media` с 6-ю `double`'ами):

*Было*

```
void Run()
{
    var num = 5;

    PrintLine(num);
}
void PrintLine(int value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

*Стало*

```
void Run()
{
    var num = 5;

    PrintLine(num); // не `PrintLine(in num)`, т. к. этот код для нас read-only
}
void PrintLine(in int value) // добавили `in`
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Появилась проблема: метод используется во многих местах *без* `in`, но нам очень нужно, чтобы все они резко стали использоваться *с* `in`, при этом мы *не можем* изменять *тело* метода, но *можем* изменять *сигнатуру* метода. Разработчики нашли решение: просто сделать его [`in`] неявным. Таким образом проблема устраняется перманентно – нужно только изменить сигнатуру метода, как у *всех* во всём остальном мире используется `in`!

Таким образом ключевое слово `in` мы вообще можем не использовать внутри тела метода, а только объявить в сигнатуре метода, причём как в новом проекте, так и в старом.

Конечно, для большей ясности лучше в новых проектах *нужно* писать именно так:

```
PrintLine(in num);
```

…но для старых проектов эта фича является просто незаменимой (и ладно Microsoft – они могут заменить их на `in`, хотя это и сложно, но возможно; проблема в не-Microsoft приложениях). Лично я ввёл бы какое-нибудь предупреждение при неявной записи `in` (увы, из-за причины описанной выше, только предупреждение, а не ошибка).

Но, конечно, при таком подходе может возникнуть конфликт. Однако Microsoft подразумевали, что методы вида:

```
PrintLine(in int value); // тоже самое, что и `PrintLine(int)`, только с копированием *значения*
PrintLine(int value); // тоже самое, что и `PrintLine(in int)`, только с копированием *ссылки*
```

…будут иметь одинаковое тело (ну, только если будет происходить рекурсивный вызов, то тогда можно (точнее *нужно*) заменить `PrintLine(num)` → `PrintLine(in num)`). Если у методов будет не одинаковое тело, это можно считать ошибкой в коде на уровне с этим:

```
throw new InvalidProgramException("Overloads have not same bodies");
```

…т. к. пользователи (если это либа, или вы, если это приложение) этих методов ожидают, что у них одинаковое тело, просто там добавили в сигнатуре `in`.

Хотя не совсем понятно зачем брать и создавать 2-е перегрузки, ведь вы "либо by-val, либо by-ref" – оба использовать не целесообразно (ну или у меня слабая фантазия и мне в голову не приходят идеи, где это можно было бы использовать).

---

Итоги:

- Неявное применение `in` не является косяком
- Оно [применение `in`] было внедрено для совместимости
- 2 перегрузки: с и без `in` – должны иметь (за редким исключением) одинаковые тела
- Использование их [перегрузок] не является оправданным (или я не прав)

Comment: _нужно только изменить сигнатуру метода, как у всех во всём остальном мире используется in_ - сперва было именно так. Но потом - [in method overload resolution tiebreaker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-3#in-method-overload-resolution-tiebreaker) - начиная с C# 7.3 недостаточно поменять сигнатуру метода, нужно и при вызове явно указывать `in`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, не знал (я просто всегда ставил `in` и не парился). сейчас исправлю, или это уже не нужно?